# Why doesn't IdentityServer consider the url valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

My redirectUrl = "https://localhost:5000/download-product2/%2Fdbforge%2Fsql%2Fsql-tools%2Fsqltoolsstd.exe/viktorbl@devart.com"

I have a code:

```
private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;

public void Login(LoginModel model) 
{
    if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl)) 
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

IdentityServer does not consider my ***redirectUrl*** valid.
Why is it change?
Help me please

Answer (score 0):

To get anyone to answer this question in a specific manner, you need to be more specific.

What errors are you getting?

Are you running your IdentityServer on localhost?

Can you get to that link from the browser?

"localhost" in your URL says that the resource is hosted on your machine. If your IdentityServer instance is not hosted on the same machine, then it will not be able to connect to it (if it uses connection check for validation). But you will still be able to access it from the browser on the same machine.

However, there also might be special logic that IdentityServer applies to URL validation. Perhaps it doesn't like the ".exe" bit in the URL. This is a fairly common anti-malware practice to consider such URLs as invalid. Perhaps you can't use file download link as a redirect (which this may be based on the URL structure).

The best way to find out what the problem is caused by is to look up the validation logic yourself. IdentityServer is open source and its code is available on GitHub. You can select the version you are using, clone the repository locally and look up the URL validation logic.

The easiest way to find where the validation logic is located is to search the repository for the error message that you are getting and then tracing the code back to figure out what generates this message.

The code for all versions of IdentityServer is available here:

https://github.com/IdentityServer